# Json Result- how to remove quotes

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my code

```
Swipe data = Array[2] : 
                 0:object 
                     id : "1"  latitude : "76.23" longitude:"21.92" 
                 1:object 
                     id:"2" latitude:"10.23" longitude:"12.92"

var abc=[];

for(_i = 0; _i < swipe_data.length; _i++)
{

     var tmp = swipe_data[_i];
     var t1 = [swipe_data[_i]['latitude'], swipe_data[_i]['longitude']];
     abc[tmp.id] = JSON.stringify(t1);
 }
 console.log(abc);
```

Output of abc is -

```
 [1: "["76.2350","21.9253"]", 3: "["10.5650","21.3653"]", 6: "["60.5650","55.3653"]"]
```

this is json string

> but i need output like this -  {"1": [76.235,21.9253], "3":
>   [10.565,21.3653], "6": [60.565,55.3653]}

Any Solution for this.?

Comment: please also share the`swipe_data`

Comment: convert swipe_data[i] to float using parseFloat function.

Comment: give value for swipe_data - edit u r question

Comment: if you want help, be helpful by providing swipe_data..we cannot make the data for the question.

Comment: What You need to do is this : abc[tmp.id] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t1));

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to  use Object key value pair for convert swipe data to this pattern...?

Comment: @VincyJoseph Taking abc as a `new Object` instead of an `Array` may help you.

Comment: You're using strings where you want numbers, and numbers where you want strings-why not start with what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parseFloat`,

```
var abc = new Object();
for(_i = 0; _i < swipe_data.length; _i++){
    var t1 = [parseFloat(swipe_data[_i]['latitude']), parseFloat(swipe_data[_i]['longitude'])];
    abc[tmp.id] = t1
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(abc));
```

Try running this code, it should work.

Note :

1. `abc` should be an `Object` not an `Array`.
2. Do not `JSON.stringify` while asssigning the value to the `key`.
3. Perform  `JSON.stringify` once you have all the key values updated in your `Object`.

Comment: He also has quotes around the square brackets. This answer won't fix that issue.

Comment: Using this output is - [1: "[76.235,21.9253]", 3: "[10.565,21.3653]", 6: "[60.565,55.3653]"]

Comment: but i need like this -  {"1": [76.235,21.9253], "3": [10.565,21.3653], "6": [60.565,55.3653]}

Comment: using this I'm getting output as string  but i need to get as integer array

Comment: @VincyJoseph Then don't use stringify. Or else you can parse the string to access all keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious solution is this:

```
var abc=[];

 for(_i = 0; _i < swipe_data.length; _i++)
{

     var tmp = swipe_data[_i];
     var t1 = [swipe_data[_i]['latitude'], swipe_data[_i]['longitude']];
     abc[tmp.id] = JSON.stringify(t1);
     abc[tmp.id] = abc[tmp.id].replace('"','');
 }
 console.log(abc);
```

All that does is replace any quotation marks in the string with nothing, effectively removing them.